# Is it possible after making an action or in my case creating an event in calender then the page automatically scrolls down using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

How to scroll down after making an event in calnder (code below), then page scrolls down automatically ? to end of the page or can be even adjust it ?

calender.php

```
<?php
include("includes/header.php");
include("includes/inavindexdiary.php");
?>

<section>
                <p><a class="button" href="index.php">E T U S I V U</a><a class="button" 
                href="analysointi.php">A N A L Y S O I N T I</a><a class="button" href="calender.php">K A L E N T E R I</a><a class="button" 
                href="profile.php">P R O F I I L I</a><a class="button" href="info.php">I N F O</a>
</section>


<form action="daily-entery.php">
    <button id="Päiväkirjamerkintä" type="submit">Move to kysely sivulla</button>
</form>



<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: "fetch-event.php",
        displayEventTime: false,
        eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
            if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                event.allDay = true;
            } else {
                event.allDay = false;
            }

        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');

            if (title) {
                var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'add-event.php',
                    data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        displayMessage("Added Successfully");
                        console.log("Added Successfully" + '  '+ title+'  '+ start+'  '+ end+'  ');
                    }
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                true
                        );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        
        editable: true,
        eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'edit-event.php',
                        data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (response) {
                            displayMessage("Updated Successfully");
                        }
                    });
                },
        eventClick: function (event) {
            var deleteMsg = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
            if (deleteMsg) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete-event.php",
                    data: "id=" + event.id,
                    success: function (response) {
                        //if(parseInt(response) > 0) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                            displayMessage("Deleted Successfully");

                        //}
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });
});

function displayMessage(message) {
        $(".response").html("<div class='success'>"+message+"</div>");
    setInterval(function() { $(".success").fadeOut(); }, 1000);
}
</script>



    <div class="response"></div>
    <div id='calendar'></div>

    <div class="slogancontainer">
    
    <hr>
        <article>   
        <p class="slogan">"Love your heart, it loves you" </p>
        </article>
    </div>

  <?php
  include("includes/footer.php")
  ?>
```

add-event.php   where i add the events :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php

require_once "db.php";

$title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "";
$start = isset($_POST['start']) ? $_POST['start'] : "";
$end = isset($_POST['end']) ? $_POST['end'] : "";


//kirjautuneen käyttäjän userID?
$data2['email'] = $_SESSION['semail'];
//var_dump($data1);
$sql1 = "SELECT id FROM otium where email =  :email";
$kysely1 = $DBH->prepare($sql1);
$kysely1->execute($data2);
$tulos1 = $kysely1->fetch();

$data1['userID'] = $tulos1[0];

try {
    //Tiedot kantaan
    var_dump($_POST);

    $data1['title'] = $_POST['title'];
    $data1['start'] = $_POST['start'];
    $data1['end'] = $_POST['end'];

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_events (title, start, end, userID) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :userID);");
    $STH->execute($data1);

    $data4['userID'] = $data1['userID'];
    $sql4 = "SELECT start FROM tbl_events where userID =:userID ORDER BY start DESC LIMIT 10";

    $kysely4 = $DBH->prepare($sql4);
    $kysely4->execute($data4);
    $tulos2 = $kysely4->fetch();

    $_SESSION["startDate"] = $tulos2[0];
    $_SESSION['startDatelomake'] = $_POST['start'];

    file_put_contents('log/DBErrors.txt', 'Päiväys:' . $_SESSION["startDate"], FILE_APPEND);

    file_put_contents('log/DBErrors.txt', "\n Merkintä hhhhhhhh on:"  . $title . "  " . $start . "  " . $end . "  " . ' id ' . $data1['userID'] . ' email ' . $_SESSION['semail'], FILE_APPEND);
    if (!$result) {
        $result = mysqli_error($DBH);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Yhteysvirhe: " . $e->getMessage();
    file_put_contents('log/DBErrors.txt', 'Connection: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

?>
```

So after adding an event i would be scrolled down automatically, reaason why there is an form to be to be filled and submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below part of your code, add a [scrollBy()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollby.asp) method. This allows you to set the scroll distance.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'add-event.php',
    data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        displayMessage("Added Successfully");
        console.log("Added Successfully" + '  '+ title+'  '+ start+'  '+ end+'  ');
        window.scrollBy(0, 100);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thnks this works just fine! i thought even more complicated.